# JSON Hyper-Schema: different schemas for GET and POST

Tags: json, jsonschema

I want to describe an API that has fields which allows for different ways to define values when POSTing an item, but only ever output in the field in one specific way.

For example, I might want to describe an API where an item can be created or updated like this: `{"name": "Task", "due": "2014-12-31"}` or like this: `{"name": "Task", "due": {"$date": 1419984000000}}`, but it is only ever returned from the API in the first way.

The schema for POST/PUT could therefore be:

```
{
    "type": "object"
    "properties": {
        "name": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "due": {
            "oneOf": [
                {
                    "type": "string",
                    "format": "date"
                },
                {
                    "type": "object",
                    "properties": {
                        "$date": {
                            "type": "number"
                        }
                    },
                    "required": ["$date"],
                    "additionalProperties": false
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Whereas the schema for access via GET would be much simpler:

```
{
    "type": "object"
    "properties": {
        "name": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "due": {
            "type": "string",
            "format": "date"
        }
    }
}
```

It would be good for consumers of the API to know that they only have to account for one possible output method rather then all of them.

Is there any accepted standard approach to specify the different schemas within the context of JSON Hyper-Schema? I've thought about specifying these differences via the `"links"` property, but I do not know what `"rel"` I would define these schemas under and it seems very-non-standard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understood correctly, and you want to specify one schema per operation you can do it with standard hyper-schema. Let's see and example for a post operation:

```
{
  "description": "create an item.",
  "href": "/items",
  "method": "POST",
  "rel": "create",
  "schema": {
    "$ref": "#/api/createitem"
  },
  "title": "Create an item"
}
```

The actual schema that is required is referenced in "schema" property through "$ref".

If you also wanted to describe the response types, then you could use "targetSchema" property. Be aware that this is advisory only (as it is [explained in the docs](http://json-schema.org/latest/json-schema-hypermedia.html#anchor31))

Comment: Right, but this one (`"create"`) is only for creating an item, not for updating one and `"update"` is not in the standard.

Comment: update is not a valid relation type. Please have a look to the following RFC: http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5988.txt I think you are confusing relation types with CRUD operations. It seems you need "rel":"self" and "href": "{id}" or some other URI that identifies the resource that is going to be updated.

Comment: I suppose the standard relation would be ["edit"](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5023#section-11.1) even though that one is also pretty ambiguous. If "rel": "self" could be repeated twice (I am not sure if it can), there could be a normal one with "method": "GET" and one for updating with method "POST".

Comment: You can repeat. GET can have "self", and "instances" and many other relation types. And yes, "rel":"edit" would be a good choice for a "PUT" operation, for instance. Obviously more docs and examples on this are needed (there are not hyper-schema samples in json-schema.org!!). The best practical source I'm aware of is the work of Heroku guys: https://blog.heroku.com/archives/2014/1/8/json_schema_for_heroku_platform_api

Comment: I mean repeat as in have the "rel": "self" present twice with different methods. Heroku uses "rel": "update".

Comment: Interesting related discussion in json-schema group: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/json-schema/hyper-schema/json-schema/UM7oM1owQlM/rt4FAhItbzIJ I think this is more related to API-design and open. I hope your initial question is solved (yes, you can have several schemas for different operations, methods, relation types, return types, etc. and can use a bunch of relation types to indicate the client the expected behaviour).